# To construct a right triangle given the hypotenuse and sum of two legs

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

**NOTE:** I want a hint only.

> A compass and a straightedge construction:Given a hypotenuse and the sum of lengths of the legs,we need to construct a right triangle.

**MY TRY:** From any ray $BE$, ,let us cut off $BC$ equal to our hypotenuse.Now we draw a circle with the hypotenuse as diameter.Now,if we take any point on the circle and join it with the end points of the hypotenuse,we will have a right triangle by Thales' theorem.

**BACKTRACKING:** As is often the case,first assuming that we have constructed our figure and then trying to reverse-engineer the steps helps in construction of the required figure.Suppose we have $\Delta ABC$ inscribed in a circle with $\angle A$ the right angle.We extend one of the legs $BA$ to $K$ such that $BK$ is equal to the sum of the legs of our triangle.Then $AK=AC$ and therefore $\angle AKC=\angle ACK$. Similarly,we extend $AC$ to $L$ such that it is equal to the sum of the legs.Then we can argue about angle equality the same way.But this is not helping me in constructing the right triangle.

A hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't we first calculate the sides then construct? Is it allowed?

Comment: @Sawarnik,you can calculate the sides if you like,but how are you going to construct them using an unmarked ruler?Moreover,what if the sides are irrational?More importantly,compass and straightedge constructions don't allow such computations,so far as I know.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209342/construction-of-a-right-triangle?rq=1

Comment: @Sawarnik,thanks for spotting the duplicate.